# Screen-space distance along line strip in GLSL

Tags: opengl, glsl, geometry-shader

When rendering a line strip, how do I get the distance of a fragment to the start point of the whole strip along the line in pixels?

When rendering a single line segment between two points in 3D, the distance between those two points in screen space is simply the Euclidean distance between their 2D projections. If I render this segment, I can interpolate (layout qualifier noperspective in GLSL) the screen-space distance from the start point along the line for each fragment.

When rendering a line strip, however, this does not work, because in the geometry shader, I only have information about the start and end point of the current segment, not all previous segments. So what I can calculate with the method above is just the distance of each fragment to the start point of the *line segment*, not to the start point of the *line strip*. But this is what I want to achieve.

What do I need that for: stylized line rendering. E.g., coloring a polyline according to its screen coverage (length in pixels), adding a distance mark every 50 pixels, alternating multiple textures along the line strip, ...

What I currently do is:

- project every point of the line beforehand on the CPU
- calculate the lengths of all projected line segments in pixels
- store the lengths in a buffer as vertex attribute (vertex 0 has distance 0, vertex 1 has the length of the segment 0->1, vertex 2 has the length 0->1 + 1->2, ...)
- in the geometry shader, create the line segments and use the distances calculated on the CPU
- interpolate the values without perspective correction for each fragment

This works, but there has to be a better way to do this. It's not feasible to project a few hundred or thousand line points on the CPU each frame. Is there a smart way to calculate this in the geometry shader? What I have is the world-space position of the start and end point of the current line segment, I have the world-space distance of both points to the start point of the line strip along the line (again vertex attribute 0, 0->1, 0->1 + 1->2, ...) and I can provided any other uniform data about the line strip (total length in world space units, number of segments, ...).

**Edit:** I do not want to compute the Euclidean distance to the start point of the line strip, but the distance *along the whole line*, i.e. the sum of the lengths of all projected line segments up to the current fragment.

Comment: This is not going to work in any reasonable way in a vertex or geometry shader, since this introduces a dependency between the different shader invocations, as you need to accumulate the lenghts of "previous" segments. You will need to precalculate that before rendering. It does not mean that this cannot be done in parallel, as you in principle can calculate the lenght of each segment in parallel, and later hierarchically sum them up. This could be done with a compute shader. Using multiple passes with transform feedback might also work. But neither approach will be straight-forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought I was just missing something here and my task could be solved by simple perspective calculation magic. Thanks derhass for pointing out the pointlessness of my quest.

As always, formulating the problem was already half the solution. When you know what to look for ("continuous parameterization of a line"), you can stumble upon the [paper](http://gfx.cs.princeton.edu/gfx/pubs/Cole_2010_TFM/)

> Forrester Cole and Adam Finkelstein. Two Fast Methods for High-Quality Line Visibility. IEEE Transactions on Visualization and Computer Graphics 16(5), February 2010.

which deals with this very problem. The solution is similar to what derhass already proposed. Cole and Finkelstein use a *segment atlas* which they calculate per frame on the GPU. It includes a list of all projected line points (among other attributes such as visibility) to keep track of the position along the line at each fragment. This segment atlas is computed in a framebuffer, as the paper (draft) dates back to 2009. Implementing the same method in a compute shader and storing the results in a buffer seems like the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I see two ways:

You can use the vertex shader. Add the start coordinates of the line strip as additional values of each vertex of the line. The vertex shader can then compute the distance to the start point and pass them interpolated to the fragment shader. There you have to rescale them to receive pixel values.

Or, you can tell the vertex shader about the start coordinates of each line strip by using uniforms. There you would need to transform them like the vertex coordinates are transformed and move them towards the fragment shader. There you would have to transform them to pixel coordinates and calculate the distance to the actual fragment.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question, or I misunderstand your answer. I do not want to compute the Euclidean distance to the start point of the line strip, but the distance _along the line_, i.e. the sum of the lengths of all projected line segments up to the current fragment. Simply transforming the start point won't gain me anything.